# PySpark - Explode the XML data row wise

Tags: xml, pyspark, databricks

I have a PySpark DF with a XML data in a string column as shown below -

[image]

The XML data is as below -

```
<FormValues>
    <FieldValues>
        <FieldValue Id="TEST">
            <Robs AsOfDate="2023-09-02T12:00:00-06:00">
                <Rob col1="5" col2="TEST" Remaining="313.094">
                    <Allocation Name="Test123" Quantity="8.5"/>
                    <Allocation Name="Test456" Quantity="1.6"/>
                    <Allocation Name="Test789" Quantity="0.4"/>
                    <Allocation Name="Test135" Quantity="0.1"/>
                </Rob>
            </Robs>
        </FieldValue>
    </FieldValues>
</FormValues>
```

I am looking to **explode** this into 4 rows, since `Allocation` tag is repeated 4 times for col1 = "5". This is completely dynamic and it may have more such records.

Failed attempts - Both of them provide only the first row `<Allocation Name="Test123" Quantity="8.5"/>` -

1. Using PySpark **explode** function and various functions like `posexplode_outer, xpath_array, from_xml`

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode, expr

# Explode the formData column and parse the XML data
exploded_df = df.withColumn("formData", expr("posexplode_outer(xpath_array(formData, '/FormValues/FieldValues/FieldValue/Rob'))")) \
                .selectExpr("firstname", "lastname", "gender", "formData.*")

# Show the resulting DataFrame
exploded_df.show(truncate=False)
```

2. Using Databricks - 'xpath_string' function -

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode, expr

# Use Databricks' xpath_string function to extract data from the XML
exploded_df = df.withColumn("Rob", expr("xpath_string(formData, '/FormValues/FieldValues/FieldValue/Robs')"))

# Show the resulting DataFrame
exploded_df.display(truncate=False)
```

Expected output - 4 rows -
[image]

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it. Basically I asked the Robs node to be made into ROW i.e `.option("rowTag", "Robs")`. Then onwards its normal data wrangling.

```
import sys
from pyspark import SparkContext, SQLContext
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("MyApp") \
    .config("spark.jars", "file:/path/to/spark-jars/spark-xml_2.12-0.16.0.jar") \
    .getOrCreate()

sc = spark.sparkContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

input_path_xml = "../data/application_job.xml"


df = sqlContext.read \
    .format("com.databricks.spark.xml") \
    .option("rowTag", "Robs") \
    .load(input_path_xml)

print("Show the dataframe")
df.show(n=100, truncate=False)

print("Schema here")
df.printSchema()

df = df.withColumnRenamed("_AsOfDate", "AsOfDate")
df = df.withColumn("col1", F.col("Rob._col1"))
df = df.withColumn("col2", F.col("Rob._col2"))
df = df.withColumn("Remaining", F.col("Rob._Remaining"))
df = df.withColumn("Allocation", F.col("Rob.Allocation")).drop("Rob")

print("Show the dataframe")
df.show(n=100, truncate=False)
print("Schema here")
df.printSchema()


df = df.withColumn("Allocation_Element", F.explode(F.col("Allocation"))).drop("Allocation")
print("Show the dataframe")
df.show(n=100, truncate=False)



df = df.withColumn("Allocation_Name", F.col("Allocation_Element._Name"))\
    .withColumn("Allocation_Quantity", F.col("Allocation_Element._Quantity"))\
    .drop("Allocation_Element")
print("Show the dataframe")
df.show(n=100, truncate=False)
```

Output :

```
Show the dataframe
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+
|Rob                                                                                                          |_AsOfDate                |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+
|{[{Test123, 8.5, null}, {Test456, 1.6, null}, {Test789, 0.4, null}, {Test135, 0.1, null}], 313.094, 5, TEST1}|2023-09-02T12:00:00-06:00|
|{[{Test123, 8.5, null}, {Test456, 1.6, null}, {Test789, 0.4, null}, {Test135, 0.1, null}], 414.094, 6, TEST2}|2023-09-02T12:00:77-07:00|
|{[{Test123, 8.5, null}, {Test456, 1.6, null}, {Test789, 0.4, null}, {Test135, 0.1, null}], 515.094, 7, TEST3}|2023-09-02T12:00:88-08:00|
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+

Schema here
root
 |-- Rob: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Allocation: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- _Name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- _Quantity: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- _VALUE: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _Remaining: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _col1: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _col2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _AsOfDate: string (nullable = true)

Show the dataframe
+-------------------------+----+-----+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|AsOfDate                 |col1|col2 |Remaining|Allocation                                                                              |
+-------------------------+----+-----+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|2023-09-02T12:00:00-06:00|5   |TEST1|313.094  |[{Test123, 8.5, null}, {Test456, 1.6, null}, {Test789, 0.4, null}, {Test135, 0.1, null}]|
|2023-09-02T12:00:77-07:00|6   |TEST2|414.094  |[{Test123, 8.5, null}, {Test456, 1.6, null}, {Test789, 0.4, null}, {Test135, 0.1, null}]|
|2023-09-02T12:00:88-08:00|7   |TEST3|515.094  |[{Test123, 8.5, null}, {Test456, 1.6, null}, {Test789, 0.4, null}, {Test135, 0.1, null}]|
+-------------------------+----+-----+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

Schema here
root
 |-- AsOfDate: string (nullable = true)
 |-- col1: long (nullable = true)
 |-- col2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Remaining: double (nullable = true)
 |-- Allocation: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- _Name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _Quantity: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _VALUE: string (nullable = true)

Show the dataframe
+-------------------------+----+-----+---------+--------------------+
|AsOfDate                 |col1|col2 |Remaining|Allocation_Element  |
+-------------------------+----+-----+---------+--------------------+
|2023-09-02T12:00:00-06:00|5   |TEST1|313.094  |{Test123, 8.5, null}|
|2023-09-02T12:00:00-06:00|5   |TEST1|313.094  |{Test456, 1.6, null}|
|2023-09-02T12:00:00-06:00|5   |TEST1|313.094  |{Test789, 0.4, null}|
|2023-09-02T12:00:00-06:00|5   |TEST1|313.094  |{Test135, 0.1, null}|
|2023-09-02T12:00:77-07:00|6   |TEST2|414.094  |{Test123, 8.5, null}|
|2023-09-02T12:00:77-07:00|6   |TEST2|414.094  |{Test456, 1.6, null}|
|2023-09-02T12:00:77-07:00|6   |TEST2|414.094  |{Test789, 0.4, null}|
|2023-09-02T12:00:77-07:00|6   |TEST2|414.094  |{Test135, 0.1, null}|
|2023-09-02T12:00:88-08:00|7   |TEST3|515.094  |{Test123, 8.5, null}|
|2023-09-02T12:00:88-08:00|7   |TEST3|515.094  |{Test456, 1.6, null}|
|2023-09-02T12:00:88-08:00|7   |TEST3|515.094  |{Test789, 0.4, null}|
|2023-09-02T12:00:88-08:00|7   |TEST3|515.094  |{Test135, 0.1, null}|
+-------------------------+----+-----+---------+--------------------+

Show the dataframe
+-------------------------+----+-----+---------+---------------+-------------------+
|AsOfDate                 |col1|col2 |Remaining|Allocation_Name|Allocation_Quantity|
+-------------------------+----+-----+---------+---------------+-------------------+
|2023-09-02T12:00:00-06:00|5   |TEST1|313.094  |Test123        |8.5                |
|2023-09-02T12:00:00-06:00|5   |TEST1|313.094  |Test456        |1.6                |
|2023-09-02T12:00:00-06:00|5   |TEST1|313.094  |Test789        |0.4                |
|2023-09-02T12:00:00-06:00|5   |TEST1|313.094  |Test135        |0.1                |
|2023-09-02T12:00:77-07:00|6   |TEST2|414.094  |Test123        |8.5                |
|2023-09-02T12:00:77-07:00|6   |TEST2|414.094  |Test456        |1.6                |
|2023-09-02T12:00:77-07:00|6   |TEST2|414.094  |Test789        |0.4                |
|2023-09-02T12:00:77-07:00|6   |TEST2|414.094  |Test135        |0.1                |
|2023-09-02T12:00:88-08:00|7   |TEST3|515.094  |Test123        |8.5                |
|2023-09-02T12:00:88-08:00|7   |TEST3|515.094  |Test456        |1.6                |
|2023-09-02T12:00:88-08:00|7   |TEST3|515.094  |Test789        |0.4                |
|2023-09-02T12:00:88-08:00|7   |TEST3|515.094  |Test135        |0.1                |
+-------------------------+----+-----+---------+---------------+-------------------+
```

Input file for the above output:

```
<FormValues>
    <FieldValues>
        <FieldValue Id="TEST">
            <Robs AsOfDate="2023-09-02T12:00:00-06:00">
                <Rob col1="5" col2="TEST1" Remaining="313.094">
                    <Allocation Name="Test123" Quantity="8.5"/>
                    <Allocation Name="Test456" Quantity="1.6"/>
                    <Allocation Name="Test789" Quantity="0.4"/>
                    <Allocation Name="Test135" Quantity="0.1"/>
                </Rob>
            </Robs>
        </FieldValue>
    </FieldValues>
</FormValues>
<FormValues>
    <FieldValues>
        <FieldValue Id="TEST">
            <Robs AsOfDate="2023-09-02T12:00:77-07:00">
                <Rob col1="6" col2="TEST2" Remaining="414.094">
                    <Allocation Name="Test123" Quantity="8.5"/>
                    <Allocation Name="Test456" Quantity="1.6"/>
                    <Allocation Name="Test789" Quantity="0.4"/>
                    <Allocation Name="Test135" Quantity="0.1"/>
                </Rob>
            </Robs>
        </FieldValue>
    </FieldValues>
</FormValues>
<FormValues>
    <FieldValues>
        <FieldValue Id="TEST">
            <Robs AsOfDate="2023-09-02T12:00:88-08:00">
                <Rob col1="7" col2="TEST3" Remaining="515.094">
                    <Allocation Name="Test123" Quantity="8.5"/>
                    <Allocation Name="Test456" Quantity="1.6"/>
                    <Allocation Name="Test789" Quantity="0.4"/>
                    <Allocation Name="Test135" Quantity="0.1"/>
                </Rob>
            </Robs>
        </FieldValue>
    </FieldValues>
</FormValues>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a different way to solve the issue. I am using spark-xml's library's functions to convert xml column into a dataframe struct. To use those functions, I created two python functions which internally call java methods. Then onwards the data wrangling can be similar.

```
import sys
from pyspark import SparkContext, SQLContext
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.column import Column
from pyspark.sql.types import _parse_datatype_json_string
from pyspark.mllib.common import _py2java, _java2py


from pyspark.sql import DataFrameReader

spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("MyApp") \
    .config("spark.jars", "file:/path/to/spark-jars/spark-xml_2.12-0.16.0.jar") \
    .getOrCreate()

sc = spark.sparkContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)


def from_xml(col, schema, options={}):
  scala_datatype = spark._jsparkSession.parseDataType(schema.json())
  scala_options = sc._jvm.PythonUtils.toScalaMap(options)
  jc = sc._jvm.com.databricks.spark.xml.functions.from_xml(col._jc if isinstance(col, Column) else col, scala_datatype, scala_options)
  return Column(jc)


def schema_of_xml(python_rdd, options={}):
    spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
    ## convert python rdd to java rdd
    javaRDD = _py2java(sc, python_rdd)
    scala_options = sc._jvm.PythonUtils.toScalaMap(options)
    jdataset = sqlContext._ssql_ctx.createDataset(
        javaRDD.rdd(),
        sqlContext._jvm.Encoders.STRING())

    return _parse_datatype_json_string(
        getattr(getattr(sc._jvm.com.databricks.spark.xml, "package$"), "MODULE$").schema_of_xml(jdataset, scala_options).json())


input_path_xml = "../data/application_job_nested.csv"


df = sqlContext.read \
    .format("com.databricks.spark.csv") \
    .csv(input_path_xml)

column_names_list = ["firstName", "lastName", "xml_tree"]
df1_mod = df.toDF(*column_names_list)



print("Show the dataframe")
df1_mod.show(n=100, truncate=False)
print("Schema here")
df1_mod.printSchema()


stringRDDwithRowSchemaWrapper = df1_mod.select("xml_tree").rdd.map(lambda x: x["xml_tree"])
payloadSchema = schema_of_xml(stringRDDwithRowSchemaWrapper)
print(payloadSchema)


df1_parsed = df1_mod.withColumn("parsed", from_xml(F.col("xml_tree"), payloadSchema)).drop("xml_tree")

print("parsed schema here")
df1_parsed.printSchema()


print("Show the parsed dataframe")
df1_parsed.show(n=100, truncate=False)

df1_parsed_mod = df1_parsed.withColumn("Robs", F.col("parsed.FieldValues.FieldValue.Robs")).drop("parsed")
df1_parsed_mod = df1_parsed_mod.withColumn("AsOfDate", F.col("Robs._AsOfDate"))
df1_parsed_mod = df1_parsed_mod.withColumn("Rob", F.col("Robs.Rob")).drop("Robs")


df1_parsed_mod = df1_parsed_mod.withColumn("col1", F.col("Rob._col1"))
df1_parsed_mod = df1_parsed_mod.withColumn("col2", F.col("Rob._col2"))
df1_parsed_mod = df1_parsed_mod.withColumn("Remaining", F.col("Rob._Remaining"))
df1_parsed_mod = df1_parsed_mod.withColumn("Allocation", F.col("Rob.Allocation")).drop("Rob")

print("Show the intermediate dataframe")
df1_parsed_mod.show(n=100, truncate=False)
print("Schema here")
df1_parsed_mod.printSchema()


df1_parsed_mod = df1_parsed_mod.withColumn("Allocation_Element", F.explode(F.col("Allocation"))).drop("Allocation")
print("Show the dataframe")
df1_parsed_mod.show(n=100, truncate=False)
print("Schema here")
df1_parsed_mod.printSchema()



df1_parsed_mod = df1_parsed_mod.withColumn("Allocation_Name", F.col("Allocation_Element._Name"))\
    .withColumn("Allocation_Quantity", F.col("Allocation_Element._Quantity"))\
    .drop("Allocation_Element")
print("Show the FINAL Required dataframe")
df1_parsed_mod.show(n=100, truncate=False)
```

Ouput :

```
Show the dataframe
+---------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|firstName|lastName|xml_tree                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  |
+---------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|James    |Smith   |<FormValues><FieldValues><FieldValue Id="TEST"><Robs AsOfDate="2023-09-02T12:00:00-06:00"><Rob col1="5" col2="TEST1" Remaining="313.094"><Allocation Name="Test123" Quantity="8.5"/><Allocation Name="Test456" Quantity="1.6"/><Allocation Name="Test789" Quantity="0.4"/><Allocation Name="Test135" Quantity="0.1"/></Rob></Robs></FieldValue></FieldValues></FormValues>|
|James    |Smith   |<FormValues><FieldValues><FieldValue Id="TEST"><Robs AsOfDate="2023-09-02T12:00:77-07:00"><Rob col1="6" col2="TEST2" Remaining="414.094"><Allocation Name="Test123" Quantity="8.5"/><Allocation Name="Test456" Quantity="1.6"/><Allocation Name="Test789" Quantity="0.4"/><Allocation Name="Test135" Quantity="0.1"/></Rob></Robs></FieldValue></FieldValues></FormValues>|
|James    |Smith   |<FormValues><FieldValues><FieldValue Id="TEST"><Robs AsOfDate="2023-09-02T12:00:88-08:00"><Rob col1="7" col2="TEST3" Remaining="515.094"><Allocation Name="Test123" Quantity="8.5"/><Allocation Name="Test456" Quantity="1.6"/><Allocation Name="Test789" Quantity="0.4"/><Allocation Name="Test135" Quantity="0.1"/></Rob></Robs></FieldValue></FieldValues></FormValues>|
+---------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

Schema here
root
 |-- firstName: string (nullable = true)
 |-- lastName: string (nullable = true)
 |-- xml_tree: string (nullable = true)

StructType([StructField('FieldValues', StructType([StructField('FieldValue', StructType([StructField('Robs', StructType([StructField('Rob', StructType([StructField('Allocation', ArrayType(StructType([StructField('_Name', StringType(), True), StructField('_Quantity', DoubleType(), True), StructField('_VALUE', StringType(), True)]), True), True), StructField('_Remaining', DoubleType(), True), StructField('_col1', LongType(), True), StructField('_col2', StringType(), True)]), True), StructField('_AsOfDate', StringType(), True)]), True), StructField('_Id', StringType(), True)]), True)]), True)])
parsed schema here
root
 |-- firstName: string (nullable = true)
 |-- lastName: string (nullable = true)
 |-- parsed: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- FieldValues: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- FieldValue: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- Robs: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- Rob: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- Allocation: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- _Name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- _Quantity: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- _VALUE: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- _Remaining: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- _col1: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- _col2: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- _AsOfDate: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- _Id: string (nullable = true)

Show the parsed dataframe
+---------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|firstName|lastName|parsed                                                                                                                                                |
+---------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|James    |Smith   |{{{{{[{Test123, 8.5, null}, {Test456, 1.6, null}, {Test789, 0.4, null}, {Test135, 0.1, null}], 313.094, 5, TEST1}, 2023-09-02T12:00:00-06:00}, TEST}}}|
|James    |Smith   |{{{{{[{Test123, 8.5, null}, {Test456, 1.6, null}, {Test789, 0.4, null}, {Test135, 0.1, null}], 414.094, 6, TEST2}, 2023-09-02T12:00:77-07:00}, TEST}}}|
|James    |Smith   |{{{{{[{Test123, 8.5, null}, {Test456, 1.6, null}, {Test789, 0.4, null}, {Test135, 0.1, null}], 515.094, 7, TEST3}, 2023-09-02T12:00:88-08:00}, TEST}}}|
+---------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

Show the intermediate dataframe
+---------+--------+-------------------------+----+-----+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|firstName|lastName|AsOfDate                 |col1|col2 |Remaining|Allocation                                                                              |
+---------+--------+-------------------------+----+-----+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|James    |Smith   |2023-09-02T12:00:00-06:00|5   |TEST1|313.094  |[{Test123, 8.5, null}, {Test456, 1.6, null}, {Test789, 0.4, null}, {Test135, 0.1, null}]|
|James    |Smith   |2023-09-02T12:00:77-07:00|6   |TEST2|414.094  |[{Test123, 8.5, null}, {Test456, 1.6, null}, {Test789, 0.4, null}, {Test135, 0.1, null}]|
|James    |Smith   |2023-09-02T12:00:88-08:00|7   |TEST3|515.094  |[{Test123, 8.5, null}, {Test456, 1.6, null}, {Test789, 0.4, null}, {Test135, 0.1, null}]|
+---------+--------+-------------------------+----+-----+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

Schema here
root
 |-- firstName: string (nullable = true)
 |-- lastName: string (nullable = true)
 |-- AsOfDate: string (nullable = true)
 |-- col1: long (nullable = true)
 |-- col2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Remaining: double (nullable = true)
 |-- Allocation: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- _Name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _Quantity: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _VALUE: string (nullable = true)

Show the dataframe
+---------+--------+-------------------------+----+-----+---------+--------------------+
|firstName|lastName|AsOfDate                 |col1|col2 |Remaining|Allocation_Element  |
+---------+--------+-------------------------+----+-----+---------+--------------------+
|James    |Smith   |2023-09-02T12:00:00-06:00|5   |TEST1|313.094  |{Test123, 8.5, null}|
|James    |Smith   |2023-09-02T12:00:00-06:00|5   |TEST1|313.094  |{Test456, 1.6, null}|
|James    |Smith   |2023-09-02T12:00:00-06:00|5   |TEST1|313.094  |{Test789, 0.4, null}|
|James    |Smith   |2023-09-02T12:00:00-06:00|5   |TEST1|313.094  |{Test135, 0.1, null}|
|James    |Smith   |2023-09-02T12:00:77-07:00|6   |TEST2|414.094  |{Test123, 8.5, null}|
|James    |Smith   |2023-09-02T12:00:77-07:00|6   |TEST2|414.094  |{Test456, 1.6, null}|
|James    |Smith   |2023-09-02T12:00:77-07:00|6   |TEST2|414.094  |{Test789, 0.4, null}|
|James    |Smith   |2023-09-02T12:00:77-07:00|6   |TEST2|414.094  |{Test135, 0.1, null}|
|James    |Smith   |2023-09-02T12:00:88-08:00|7   |TEST3|515.094  |{Test123, 8.5, null}|
|James    |Smith   |2023-09-02T12:00:88-08:00|7   |TEST3|515.094  |{Test456, 1.6, null}|
|James    |Smith   |2023-09-02T12:00:88-08:00|7   |TEST3|515.094  |{Test789, 0.4, null}|
|James    |Smith   |2023-09-02T12:00:88-08:00|7   |TEST3|515.094  |{Test135, 0.1, null}|
+---------+--------+-------------------------+----+-----+---------+--------------------+

Schema here
root
 |-- firstName: string (nullable = true)
 |-- lastName: string (nullable = true)
 |-- AsOfDate: string (nullable = true)
 |-- col1: long (nullable = true)
 |-- col2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Remaining: double (nullable = true)
 |-- Allocation_Element: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _Name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _Quantity: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _VALUE: string (nullable = true)

Show the FINAL Required dataframe
+---------+--------+-------------------------+----+-----+---------+---------------+-------------------+
|firstName|lastName|AsOfDate                 |col1|col2 |Remaining|Allocation_Name|Allocation_Quantity|
+---------+--------+-------------------------+----+-----+---------+---------------+-------------------+
|James    |Smith   |2023-09-02T12:00:00-06:00|5   |TEST1|313.094  |Test123        |8.5                |
|James    |Smith   |2023-09-02T12:00:00-06:00|5   |TEST1|313.094  |Test456        |1.6                |
|James    |Smith   |2023-09-02T12:00:00-06:00|5   |TEST1|313.094  |Test789        |0.4                |
|James    |Smith   |2023-09-02T12:00:00-06:00|5   |TEST1|313.094  |Test135        |0.1                |
|James    |Smith   |2023-09-02T12:00:77-07:00|6   |TEST2|414.094  |Test123        |8.5                |
|James    |Smith   |2023-09-02T12:00:77-07:00|6   |TEST2|414.094  |Test456        |1.6                |
|James    |Smith   |2023-09-02T12:00:77-07:00|6   |TEST2|414.094  |Test789        |0.4                |
|James    |Smith   |2023-09-02T12:00:77-07:00|6   |TEST2|414.094  |Test135        |0.1                |
|James    |Smith   |2023-09-02T12:00:88-08:00|7   |TEST3|515.094  |Test123        |8.5                |
|James    |Smith   |2023-09-02T12:00:88-08:00|7   |TEST3|515.094  |Test456        |1.6                |
|James    |Smith   |2023-09-02T12:00:88-08:00|7   |TEST3|515.094  |Test789        |0.4                |
|James    |Smith   |2023-09-02T12:00:88-08:00|7   |TEST3|515.094  |Test135        |0.1                |
+---------+--------+-------------------------+----+-----+---------+---------------+-------------------+
```

Input csv file for the same. :

```
James,Smith,<FormValues><FieldValues><FieldValue Id="TEST"><Robs AsOfDate="2023-09-02T12:00:00-06:00"><Rob col1="5" col2="TEST1" Remaining="313.094"><Allocation Name="Test123" Quantity="8.5"/><Allocation Name="Test456" Quantity="1.6"/><Allocation Name="Test789" Quantity="0.4"/><Allocation Name="Test135" Quantity="0.1"/></Rob></Robs></FieldValue></FieldValues></FormValues>
James,Smith,<FormValues><FieldValues><FieldValue Id="TEST"><Robs AsOfDate="2023-09-02T12:00:77-07:00"><Rob col1="6" col2="TEST2" Remaining="414.094"><Allocation Name="Test123" Quantity="8.5"/><Allocation Name="Test456" Quantity="1.6"/><Allocation Name="Test789" Quantity="0.4"/><Allocation Name="Test135" Quantity="0.1"/></Rob></Robs></FieldValue></FieldValues></FormValues>
James,Smith,<FormValues><FieldValues><FieldValue Id="TEST"><Robs AsOfDate="2023-09-02T12:00:88-08:00"><Rob col1="7" col2="TEST3" Remaining="515.094"><Allocation Name="Test123" Quantity="8.5"/><Allocation Name="Test456" Quantity="1.6"/><Allocation Name="Test789" Quantity="0.4"/><Allocation Name="Test135" Quantity="0.1"/></Rob></Robs></FieldValue></FieldValues></FormValues>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this solution, I am using the CSV data file but with xml parsing module. It works without any signification changes. Please take a look.

```
import sys
from pyspark import SparkContext, SQLContext
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("MyApp") \
    .config("spark.jars", "file:/path/to/spark-jars/spark-xml_2.12-0.16.0.jar") \
    .getOrCreate()

sc = spark.sparkContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

input_path_xml = "../data/application_job_nested.csv"


df = sqlContext.read \
    .format("com.databricks.spark.xml") \
    .option("rowTag", "Robs") \
    .load(input_path_xml)

print("Show the dataframe")
df.show(n=100, truncate=False)

print("Schema here")
df.printSchema()

df = df.withColumnRenamed("_AsOfDate", "AsOfDate")
df = df.withColumn("col1", F.col("Rob._col1"))
df = df.withColumn("col2", F.col("Rob._col2"))
df = df.withColumn("Remaining", F.col("Rob._Remaining"))
df = df.withColumn("Allocation", F.col("Rob.Allocation")).drop("Rob")

print("Show the dataframe")
df.show(n=100, truncate=False)
print("Schema here")
df.printSchema()


df = df.withColumn("Allocation_Element", F.explode(F.col("Allocation"))).drop("Allocation")
print("Show the dataframe")
df.show(n=100, truncate=False)



df = df.withColumn("Allocation_Name", F.col("Allocation_Element._Name"))\
    .withColumn("Allocation_Quantity", F.col("Allocation_Element._Quantity"))\
    .drop("Allocation_Element")
print("Show the dataframe")
df.show(n=100, truncate=False)
```

Output:

```
Show the dataframe
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+
|Rob                                                                                                          |_AsOfDate                |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+
|{[{Test123, 8.5, null}, {Test456, 1.6, null}, {Test789, 0.4, null}, {Test135, 0.1, null}], 313.094, 5, TEST1}|2023-09-02T12:00:00-06:00|
|{[{Test123, 8.5, null}, {Test456, 1.6, null}, {Test789, 0.4, null}, {Test135, 0.1, null}], 414.094, 6, TEST2}|2023-09-02T12:00:77-07:00|
|{[{Test123, 8.5, null}, {Test456, 1.6, null}, {Test789, 0.4, null}, {Test135, 0.1, null}], 515.094, 7, TEST3}|2023-09-02T12:00:88-08:00|
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+

Schema here
root
 |-- Rob: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Allocation: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- _Name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- _Quantity: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- _VALUE: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _Remaining: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _col1: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _col2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _AsOfDate: string (nullable = true)

Show the dataframe
+-------------------------+----+-----+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|AsOfDate                 |col1|col2 |Remaining|Allocation                                                                              |
+-------------------------+----+-----+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|2023-09-02T12:00:00-06:00|5   |TEST1|313.094  |[{Test123, 8.5, null}, {Test456, 1.6, null}, {Test789, 0.4, null}, {Test135, 0.1, null}]|
|2023-09-02T12:00:77-07:00|6   |TEST2|414.094  |[{Test123, 8.5, null}, {Test456, 1.6, null}, {Test789, 0.4, null}, {Test135, 0.1, null}]|
|2023-09-02T12:00:88-08:00|7   |TEST3|515.094  |[{Test123, 8.5, null}, {Test456, 1.6, null}, {Test789, 0.4, null}, {Test135, 0.1, null}]|
+-------------------------+----+-----+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

Schema here
root
 |-- AsOfDate: string (nullable = true)
 |-- col1: long (nullable = true)
 |-- col2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Remaining: double (nullable = true)
 |-- Allocation: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- _Name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _Quantity: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _VALUE: string (nullable = true)

Show the dataframe
+-------------------------+----+-----+---------+--------------------+
|AsOfDate                 |col1|col2 |Remaining|Allocation_Element  |
+-------------------------+----+-----+---------+--------------------+
|2023-09-02T12:00:00-06:00|5   |TEST1|313.094  |{Test123, 8.5, null}|
|2023-09-02T12:00:00-06:00|5   |TEST1|313.094  |{Test456, 1.6, null}|
|2023-09-02T12:00:00-06:00|5   |TEST1|313.094  |{Test789, 0.4, null}|
|2023-09-02T12:00:00-06:00|5   |TEST1|313.094  |{Test135, 0.1, null}|
|2023-09-02T12:00:77-07:00|6   |TEST2|414.094  |{Test123, 8.5, null}|
|2023-09-02T12:00:77-07:00|6   |TEST2|414.094  |{Test456, 1.6, null}|
|2023-09-02T12:00:77-07:00|6   |TEST2|414.094  |{Test789, 0.4, null}|
|2023-09-02T12:00:77-07:00|6   |TEST2|414.094  |{Test135, 0.1, null}|
|2023-09-02T12:00:88-08:00|7   |TEST3|515.094  |{Test123, 8.5, null}|
|2023-09-02T12:00:88-08:00|7   |TEST3|515.094  |{Test456, 1.6, null}|
|2023-09-02T12:00:88-08:00|7   |TEST3|515.094  |{Test789, 0.4, null}|
|2023-09-02T12:00:88-08:00|7   |TEST3|515.094  |{Test135, 0.1, null}|
+-------------------------+----+-----+---------+--------------------+

Show the dataframe
+-------------------------+----+-----+---------+---------------+-------------------+
|AsOfDate                 |col1|col2 |Remaining|Allocation_Name|Allocation_Quantity|
+-------------------------+----+-----+---------+---------------+-------------------+
|2023-09-02T12:00:00-06:00|5   |TEST1|313.094  |Test123        |8.5                |
|2023-09-02T12:00:00-06:00|5   |TEST1|313.094  |Test456        |1.6                |
|2023-09-02T12:00:00-06:00|5   |TEST1|313.094  |Test789        |0.4                |
|2023-09-02T12:00:00-06:00|5   |TEST1|313.094  |Test135        |0.1                |
|2023-09-02T12:00:77-07:00|6   |TEST2|414.094  |Test123        |8.5                |
|2023-09-02T12:00:77-07:00|6   |TEST2|414.094  |Test456        |1.6                |
|2023-09-02T12:00:77-07:00|6   |TEST2|414.094  |Test789        |0.4                |
|2023-09-02T12:00:77-07:00|6   |TEST2|414.094  |Test135        |0.1                |
|2023-09-02T12:00:88-08:00|7   |TEST3|515.094  |Test123        |8.5                |
|2023-09-02T12:00:88-08:00|7   |TEST3|515.094  |Test456        |1.6                |
|2023-09-02T12:00:88-08:00|7   |TEST3|515.094  |Test789        |0.4                |
|2023-09-02T12:00:88-08:00|7   |TEST3|515.094  |Test135        |0.1                |
+-------------------------+----+-----+---------+---------------+-------------------+
```

Input CSV file provided :

```
James,Smith,<FormValues><FieldValues><FieldValue Id="TEST"><Robs AsOfDate="2023-09-02T12:00:00-06:00"><Rob col1="5" col2="TEST1" Remaining="313.094"><Allocation Name="Test123" Quantity="8.5"/><Allocation Name="Test456" Quantity="1.6"/><Allocation Name="Test789" Quantity="0.4"/><Allocation Name="Test135" Quantity="0.1"/></Rob></Robs></FieldValue></FieldValues></FormValues>
James,Smith,<FormValues><FieldValues><FieldValue Id="TEST"><Robs AsOfDate="2023-09-02T12:00:77-07:00"><Rob col1="6" col2="TEST2" Remaining="414.094"><Allocation Name="Test123" Quantity="8.5"/><Allocation Name="Test456" Quantity="1.6"/><Allocation Name="Test789" Quantity="0.4"/><Allocation Name="Test135" Quantity="0.1"/></Rob></Robs></FieldValue></FieldValues></FormValues>
James,Smith,<FormValues><FieldValues><FieldValue Id="TEST"><Robs AsOfDate="2023-09-02T12:00:88-08:00"><Rob col1="7" col2="TEST3" Remaining="515.094"><Allocation Name="Test123" Quantity="8.5"/><Allocation Name="Test456" Quantity="1.6"/><Allocation Name="Test789" Quantity="0.4"/><Allocation Name="Test135" Quantity="0.1"/></Rob></Robs></FieldValue></FieldValues></FormValues>
```