# Pyspark Defining schema for xml file having multiple levels

Tags: xml, pyspark

I have a scenario to use xml as source. There is existing code which works fine (in databricks) where the xml schema is defined as sample below

XMLSchema = StructType([StructField('snapshot', StructType([StructField('_descriptor', StringType(), True), StructField('_timestamp', StringType(), True), StructField('_type', StringType(), True), StructField('diagnostic', ArrayType(StructType([StructField('_name', StringType(), True), StructField('collection', ArrayType(StructType([StructField('_name', StringType(), True), StructField('_type', StringType(), True), StructField('collection', ArrayType(StructType([StructField('_name', StringType(), True), StructField('_type', StringType(), True), StructField('collection', ArrayType(StructType([StructField('_name', StringType(), True)........

This works fine if the hierarchy is having single value of Snapshot. The new requirement is to have it defined so that there are can be more than 1 hierarchy of value as snapshot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBcNb.png)

Can you please help how we can define schema for more than 1 levels in hierarchy?

I tried to give as an array outside structtype, but it gave me an error. Is there a way to dynamically define schema

Comment: I tried to solve a problem similar to yours before. Take a look at the solutions. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77064318/pyspark-explode-the-xml-data-row-wise