# Methods for piggybacking on Spark's Py4J Gateway

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, py4j

I am working on a python application which relies on Py4j to communicate with a Java backend.  This application will, for the foreseeable future, exclusively be executed in the context of a Spark job operating in cluster mode.  We've added our requisite JARs to the Spark classpath (`$SPARK_HOME/jars`), and would prefer to connect to the existing Py4j gateway used to communicate with PySpark.  Connecting to this gateway is non-trivial due to the non-constant nature of the secret and port.  We would prefer to avoid spinning up a second JVM for resource reasons.

Is there a recommended approach for this sort of need?

Re-executing the gateway starting code (https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/839f0c98bd85a14eadad13f8aaac876275ded5a4/python/pyspark/java_gateway.py#L55) results in a second JVM, and more importantly, a port conflict as it attempts to spin up a second gateway on the same port.

Comment: I am ignorant about this but you can call your own java functions as well as spark's java ones like this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/77071579/3238085 . Will this not fit the solution? Sorry if you have already considered this or I am misunderstanding this.

Comment: We are already committed to py4j for our use case, and importantly, the fact that we're colocated with an active pyspark session is more coincidental than anything-- We aren't trying to make additional Spark calls (beyond what pyspark does on its own) through the gateway, but rather just take advantage of the existing gateway to reach our own unrelated code that's been loaded into the classpath.